# Trying to fetch the first element of an array and then return it to the main method

Tags: c#

Code cannot compile, trying to find a way to fetch the first element of an array and return it to the main method

```
using System;

namespace ProgramExercise10_2
{

    class PhotoDemo
    {
        class Photo
        {
            protected double[] price = { 3.99, 5.99, 9.99 };

            public photoPrice(int width, int height)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter photo width: ");
                width = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Enter photo height: ");
                height = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                if ( width == 8 && height == 10)
                {
                    double[] _price = price[1];
                    return _price;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Cannot implicitly convert double to double[]

Comment: `double _price = price[0];` `_price` should be `double`, not array. You also don't have return type in `photoPrice` method and you don't handle case where the `if` condition is never met.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you wanted, but the first element of the array is actually element 0: `double _price = price[0];`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also

```
  public photoPrice(int width, int height)
```

must be

```
 public double PhotoPrice(int width, int height)
 {
     ...
    if (width == 8 && height == 10)
    {
       return price[0]; // or price[1];
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

*naming convention C#

Answer (score 1):

```
 double[] _price = price[1];
```

should be

```
double _price = price[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of oddities about your posted code, but the below works:

```
    public double PhotoPrice()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter photo width: ");
        int width = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Enter photo height: ");
        int height = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if (width == 8 && height == 10)
        {
            double _price = price[0];
            return _price;
        }
        else return 0.0D;
    }
```

The oddities are:

- you seem to have a class (photo) enclosed (unnecessarily) inside another class (PhotoDemo)
- you have parameters in the method that if passed in are not used, but are set within the method.
- you needed a default return (see my else return...)
- you were returning the second item in the array (arrays are zero based indexed) into another array, but only needed to return it into a double. You could just return the result which would return the double, but i left it explicit.
- Your naming convention for the method is not CamelCase.

You'll still need to instantiate the class (PhotoDemo) and call the method from the static void main...